# Minor flaw in CiviCRM registration page for EFF

Tags: issues

Excuse me for being OCD = perfectionist, but when RSVPing for an EFF event, there was no [register], [Submit], [Complete your registration] etc, but only a [Review your registration].

As a professional CRM company, I'd expect CiviCRM to have something this simple be correct:

Change the "review your registration" (which DOESN'T - you're LOOKING at your information right there!!) to "register".   Maybe you're thinking that it goes through an audit process making sure data is entered in the *'d (mandatory) fields.  But still... you are submitting the registration!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that the meaning of that button changes depending on how the registration is set up and the text of the button doesn't change in line with that, unfortunately. I have a [pull request](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/20251) in to fix this in future versions.

Comment: Oh, thank you! glad for the pull request.